# Differences between a service and a singleton instance?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm developing an android application, and would like to know the difference between a service started with `startService()` and a singleton class performing the same code I put in `startService()`.

So, for example if I have a `VideoRecordingService` service set to record a video from the camera on it's start, and a `CameraRecorderClass` singleton class which have a `StartRecording()` method that also records a video from the camera, how do they differ? 
They both non-related to any activity lifecycle, and they both use the main thread to do it's work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Service is mainly used when you want to do some background operation. For eg:- Playing music in your application. So, if you don't have any Activity running you can play music using Service.

While your Singleton instance would not be working if you close your application/activity if unless you are performing it in some background task. Also, Service will restart automatically if you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand` when your Service is killed due to some reason.

So, in your case if you really want to do some long background running operation then its better to use Service instead of your Singleton instance.

Answer (score 1):

When using `startService` it creates a new instance of that class, it can have a context and do a wide range of things that the `Service` class inherits. You can create this anywhere in your application where you have a context, and you can start and stop it multiple times (using `startService` and `stopSelf`)

With a singleton class, well, its a static object that you can only have once instance of (unless you want to create more I guess?). The static object can isn't much different, however it doesn't have a context and all that nice android stuff that comes with a class (unless you pass it a context or what ever you may need).

A service can also be run without needing to invoke it by using a activity, or showing a UI, it can run in the background with no UI, and can be started using a broadcast listener without interrupting the user, as long as the service is running then the service shouldn't be automatically closed by the system, rather then if you started an async task in the singleton and then closed the activity and the activity was destroyed.

There may be more to it. But you would have to look into dalvik..